# RDLC - How to display each row from dataset in each page?

Tags: rdlc

I am having set of text boxes in the report and binding each columns in the text box from the Data set.

As of now only first record from the dataset is binding in the text box.

I need all the rows in the dataset to bind in the text boxes page wise.
Each row in the dataset bind to text boxes page wise.

First record in first page,Second record in second page ... etc.

How to achieve this? Help me to solve this...

Thanks in Advance,
Stephen.L

Answer (score 3):

I recently faced the same issue, I used some help from stackoverflow to solve the issue, u might have already figured it out but this is to help others with similar issue.

1. Make sure you have a Dataset defined for your report.
2. Add a "Table" control to the report. This seems to be needed in order to iterate the rows in your Dataset.
3. Delete the header row and two of the default columns from the table so that you are left with a single row with a single column.
4. Expand the table to the width of your layout and make it as tall as you will need for your "free form" layout.
5. By default, there is a TextBox inside the table cell. Right-click the empty table cell and choose "delete" to remove that TextBox.
6. Drag a "Rectangle" control into the empty table cell. It seems to automatically "dock" to the width/height of the table cell.
7. Now you should be able to drag the fields from your DataSet (TextBoxes, etc) into the Rectangle to produce the desired layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [List](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/lists/index.html) with [page breaks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251733%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) at the end of details group.